# How can I expand the cafe?

Tags: disney-magical-world

How am I supposed to expand the cafe? I know it can be expanded because I've visited other players cafes and there was a second floor! How do you get it? Also how many times can it expand?  Only once or multiple times? Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to earn 30 Happy Stickers. Once you do that, you need to interact with the "30" at the front of the cafe and the king will come by and give you the Cafe Extender. You can use this item to create a second floor.

And I think you can only expand it one time.